# [SQL][Bigquery] Case When to take preceding row for a condition

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

So for a table like this i want to have another column which has the reqd_col value if cond_value is > 100 and to take the previous value in other cases.

| User | cond_Value | Reqd_Col |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 159 | 12:30 |
| 123456 | 34 | 12:32 |
| 123456 | 46 | 12:35 |
| 123456 | 98 | 12:37 |
| 123456 | 123 | 12:56 |
| 123456 | 12 | 13:00 |
| 789000 | 100 | 16:00 |
| 789000 | 54 | 16:10 |
| 789000 | 23 | 16:14 |
| 789000 | 122 | 17:05 |
| 789000 | 98 | 17:08 |
| 789000 | 133 | 17:23 |

So the output should look like

| User | cond_Value | Reqd_Col | Output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 159 | 12:30 | 12:30 |
| 123456 | 34 | 12:32 | 12:30 |
| 123456 | 46 | 12:35 | 12:30 |
| 123456 | 98 | 12:37 | 12:30 |
| 123456 | 123 | 12:56 | 12:56 |
| 123456 | 12 | 13:00 | 12:56 |
| 789000 | 100 | 16:00 | 16:00 |
| 789000 | 54 | 16:10 | 16:00 |
| 789000 | 23 | 16:14 | 16:00 |
| 789000 | 122 | 17:05 | 17:05 |
| 789000 | 98 | 17:08 | 17:05 |
| 789000 | 133 | 17:23 | 17:23 |

Ideally i would like to have this as a view in BigQuery.

Comment: if cond_value is > 100, 7th row shouldn't be 16:00. am I correct ?   I thinks you're meaning cond_value is >= 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below query.

```sql
SELECT *, LAST_VALUE(IF(cond_Value >= 100, Reqd_Col, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) OVER w AS Output
  FROM sample_table
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY User ORDER BY PARSE_TIME('%R', Reqd_Col))
 ORDER BY 1, 3;

+--------+------------+----------+--------+
|  User  | cond_Value | Reqd_Col | Output |
+--------+------------+----------+--------+
| 123456 |        159 | 12:30    | 12:30  |
| 123456 |         34 | 12:32    | 12:30  |
| 123456 |         46 | 12:35    | 12:30  |
| 123456 |         98 | 12:37    | 12:30  |
| 123456 |        123 | 12:56    | 12:56  |
| 123456 |         12 | 13:00    | 12:56  |
| 789000 |        100 | 16:00    | 16:00  |
| 789000 |         54 | 16:10    | 16:00  |
| 789000 |         23 | 16:14    | 16:00  |
| 789000 |        122 | 17:05    | 17:05  |
| 789000 |         98 | 17:08    | 17:05  |
| 789000 |        133 | 17:23    | 17:23  |
+--------+------------+----------+--------+
```